# How to validate the textbox on submit?

Tags: jquery, validation

On submit I want to validate the textbox but it does not work.

```
 $( "#add" ).submit(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    if ( $( "#key" ).val() === "" ) {
        $( "span .valuewarning" ).text( "Please Enter Word" ).show();
        return;
      }
    else if($( "#value" ).val() === "")
            {
        $( "span .wordwarning" ).text( "Please Enter Meaning" ).show();
        return;
      }
```

Comment: Not much code to get help.

Comment: Please post your HTML code. Which element you are attaching `submit` event to? It should be the `form`.

Comment: So `.wordwarning` is a *descendent* of `span`? If it is the span it should be `"span.wordwarning"`

Comment: What if both are not blank?  Your preventing the default regardless...

Comment: Provide a proper problem description and relevant html. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @charlietfl i got what i were looking for Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting the span with class = 'valuewarning' to display the error message, you need to remove the space between the span and class.i.e,

`$( "span .valuewarning" )`  should be `$( "span.valuewarning" );`
`$( "span .wordwarning" )` should be `$( "span.wordwarning" );`

Adding a space between the span and class would mean looking for an element with that class within a span element.